# Two SELECT's in one query in the same table

Tags: mysql, select

I have one table:

```
id | parent_id | name
1  | NULL      | audi
2  | 1         | a5
3  | 1         | a6
4  | NULL      | opel
5  | 4         | astra
6  | 4         | vectra
```

I want get name of record and name of record's parent.

One example is to fetch the name for id=5 and its parent name.

```
id | name  | parent_name
5  | astra | opel
```

What would be SQL query for this?

My query:

```
SELECT name, parent_id FROM `cats` WHERE `id` = 5 OR `id` = 
cats.parent_id LIMIT 0 , 30
```

didn't work.

Comment: Guess you use mySQL regarding your samepl that is not working?

Answer (score 1):

This work's if you have only 1 parent at a time (no recursion):

```
SELECT a.name name, b.name parent_name
FROM tablexyz a,tablexyz b where
a.id=5 AND a.parent_id=b.id;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks you :)

It was simple. I didnt know that i can ignore "as" in query.

Comment: That is perhaps database specific. In MySql you need to use inner join  keyword instead of comma to join tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query:

```
SELECT T1.id, T1.name, T2.name as parentname
FROM TABLE1 T1
    INNER JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.id = T2.parent_id
WHERE T2.ID = 5
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0dae8/6)

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me. Please check it out.

```
select a.id,a.name,b.name as parent from cats a,cats b where b.id=a.parent_id;
```

You can add any other conditions too. (make sure to use the correct table identifier; `a` or `b`)